# Is there a way to configure git repository to reject 'git push --force'?

Tags: git

I was wondering is there a way to prevent '`git push --force`' on a repository (only on master branch)?

Assume I have remote git repository and do:

- '`git push`' to 'master'. It works.
- '`git push --force`' to 'branch-1'. It works.
- '`git push --force`' to 'master'. It is rejected.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Setting the configuration variables:

```
receive.denyNonFastForwards
receive.denyDeletes
```

will prevent any 'forced' pushes from working across all branches.

If you want finer pre-branch control then you will have to use a 'hook' on the remote repository, probably the 'update' hook.

There is a sample update hook called 'update-paranoid' that probably does what you need (and more) in the git distribution in the 'contrib' folder.

[gitweb link](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=tree;f=contrib/hooks;h=e5d46a9cb3b202b1c03a9391b4e177f474a6b1b5;hb=080cbc1275ac09445136ba429d90b5ec85e92c1c)

Comment: +1 for the hook (raw version: http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/hooks/update-paranoid;hb=080cbc1275ac09445136ba429d90b5ec85e92c1c )

Comment: any way to do this for GitHub?

Comment: `update-paranoid` on GitHub: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/hooks/update-paranoid

Answer (score 7):

**Github has already introduced the concept of protected branches!**

It can be found under `Settings -> Branches -> Protected Branches`. Feature is now available for all users - not only enterprise!

This "protection" can be enabled for any branch, and for any user, including admins.

More details here - https://help.github.com/articles/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/

So no more hooks and arbitrary code is needed.

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't present at the time of writing the OP. :)

Comment: That's only on Github, not with plain git. The original post did not mention Github.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this quick update hook to prevent non-fast-forward updates (pushes) on the "dev" branch in a repository:

```
#!/bin/sh

REFNAME=$1
OLDSHA=$2
NEWSHA=$3

if [ "refs/heads/dev" != $REFNAME ]; then
  exit 0
fi

MERGEBASE=$(git merge-base $OLDSHA $NEWSHA)
if [ $OLDSHA = $MERGEBASE ]; then
  exit 0
fi

echo "Not a fast-forward on branch dev"
exit 1
```