# Can not push changes after using git reset --hard

Tags: git, git-revert

I had a mistake and commit some changes to git which I should not have committed.
After I made the commit, I pushed my changes. 
I then used the following commands to try and reset my changes.

```
 git reset --hard head
```

Now I want to push this 'reset' to the remote repository with this command:

```
git push MyBranch
```

But I am getting this error:

```
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/branch (you should pull first)
```

I tried to use this command without any success:

```
git push -f "origin"
```

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

```
git push -f origin myBranch
```

should work (provided you are aware this can be dangerous if MyBranch was already fetched by others in their own repo)

Since 2012, you also have:

- [`git push --force-with-lease`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937476/6309) (Git 1.8.5+ Q3 2013) which is safer, and
- [`git push --force-if-includes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627761/6309) (Git 2.30+, Q1 2021), which attempts to ensure that what is being force-pushed was created *after* examining the commit at the tip of the remote ref that is about to be force-replaced.

Note: if your remote repo ('origin') has its [config](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-config) set with

```
receive.denyNonFastForwards true
```

it will deny any non fast-forward push (even when forced).
See "[Is there a way to configure git repository to reject 'git push --force'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754491/is-there-a-way-to-configure-git-repository-to-reject-git-push-force)".

---

The [OP user654019](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654019/user654019) reports

> I managed to solve the problem this time by setting `denyNonFastForwards` to `false` and using `-f` to force the push

If the OP didn't have access to the repo, he/she would have to:

- reset the local HEAD to its original position (see "[Recover from `git reset --hard?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788037/recover-from-git-reset-hard)"):
  `git reset HEAD@{1}`
- make a *new* commit which cancel your merge, as described in the [ProGit book](http://progit.org/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html), with [`git revert`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-revert):
  `git revert -m 1 HEAD~` (in your case)

By example:

```
$ git revert -m 1 [sha_of_C8]
Finished one revert.
[master 88edd6d] Revert "Merge branch 'jk/post-checkout'"
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

[image: revert a merge]

A complete discussion on how to revert a merge can [be found here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt;hb=master).

The idea remains to generate only *new* commits, including one reverting the changes introduced by the merge commit.
You then can push that new commit, as a fast-forward change.

Comment: It did not work. Probably the config is set in repository. Two quesytion: What is the best way to solve this problem if the denyNonFastForwards is true? How can I revert some mchanges (a merge) and create a new commit?

Comment: @user654019: by creating a new commit composed of changes cancelling your previous commit: use [git revert](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-revert): you will then be able to push that new commit as a fast-forward push.

Comment: The original commit was a merge and when I tried to do a revert -m 1 <commit_hash code> I got some error

Comment: similar to this one it was about not able to do a fast forward

Comment: @user654019: did you first restore your HEAD? Because the revert itself should work (as described in http://progit.org/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve the problem this time by setting denyNonFastForwards to false and using -f to force the push. I would use the solutions presented in VonC commnet next tim.

Comment: @user654019: thank you for your feedback. I have included it in the answer (as well as documentation about the `git revert`) for more visibility.

Comment: Don't forget the `--` shortcut.  This lets you use `git push -f --` pretty quickly for the same effect.

Comment: this does not work for me.  i tried `git config --get receive.denyNonFastForwards` and it displayed no output, does that mean the option is not set?  yet it refuses to let me push "error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)" but if I pull like it tells me to, eliminate the conflict, then push again, it rejects my changes "because the tip of your current branch is behind" and tell me to pull again, but if I try that it refuses with "Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files". I feel like everything I do is making this WORSE for what should have taken 5s

Comment: @Michael One: yes, two, this is a config set on the remote side, not on the client side from which you are pushing.

Comment: @Michael It is best to ask a new question, detailing the exact commands and git status illustrating the state you are in, as well as the OS and git version. That way, I or other contributors can explain to you (and, more importantly, other users who might end up in the same situation) why it took a bit more than 5 seconds

Comment: @VonC thanks, can you point me to some documentation on how to get and set the remote config?  I'm not finding it, and my naive attempts (.e.g "git remote config --get receive.denyNonFastForwards") aren't working.

Comment: @Michael the git config is simply to be executed on the remote server, which depends on its nature (you wouldn't be able to set it if the remote server is github.com for instance). Again, a detailed question with all the details would be helpful, to you and others.

Comment: Never mind, i just nuked the whole thing and re-cloned it from scratch.  The amount of time spent going down this rabbit hole is ridiculous.

Comment: @Michael I understand your frustration. Not a bad solution actually, according to xkcd ;) https://xkcd.com/1597/

Answer (score 26):

You need to specify what ref you want to push:

```
git push -f origin MyBranch
```