# Completely remove a commit from remote Git repository

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

Let's assume the commit history of the branch is as follows:

```
John Doe [0003] Third Commit
Jane Roe [0002] Second Commit
Jane Roe [0001] First commit
```

What I would like to do is to completely remove the Third Commit [0003] and replace it with the new Fourth Commit (so the Fourth becomes Third).

I used `git reset --hard 0002` to set the HEAD. I have also made some changes and what I want now is the NEW Second Commit (or the Fourth Commit) to become the OLD Third Commit [0003].

**John Doe [0003] Fourth Commit (Second Commit with changes)**

<del>John Doe [0003] Third Commit</del>

Jane Roe [0002] Second Commit

Jane Roe [0001] First commit

Answer (score 0):

`git push -f` is what I was looking for.

Ref: [Can not push changes after using git reset --hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804211/can-not-push-changes-after-using-git-reset-hard)