# Using git, how to avoid rebase and push?

Tags: git, github

I think the only rule about rebase and push is that

> After commits are pushed to a public repo, don't rebase and push

But is it true that if we only use `git push` or `git push origin <branch-name>` and never use the `--force` or `-f` flag, then it can never happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your public repo is a bare repo (meaning you can rebase anything directly on the public repo itself), and if you set the [git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) `receive.denyNonFastForwards` and `receive.denyDeletes` to true, then you should be ok.

> If set to true, `git-receive-pack` will deny a ref update which is not a fast-forward. Use this to prevent such an update via a push, **even if that push is forced**.
>
> If set to true, `git-receive-pack` will deny a ref update that deletes the ref. Use this to **prevent such a ref deletion via a push**.

See also "[Is there a way to configure git repository to reject '`git push --force`'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754491/is-there-a-way-to-configure-git-repository-to-reject-git-push-force)".

Note that those settings aren't available directly for a GitHub repo, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It is true (I think) that the remote repo will never end up in a "bad" state if you don't use `--force`, so you can't do it accidentally.

But if you rebase commits that are already on the remote, your local repo might end up in a state where you can't push to the remote repo without going through some gymnastics that defeat the point of the rebase anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You cannot rebase then push a remote tracking branch without using --force.

Answer (score 1):

Without the "-f" flag, it can never happen.
But what would you do with your branch without the ability to push it?

Rebase is mostly to keep **your** branch history nice and serial
It is safe when you are the only one that merge into that code or if you are doing it locally only.
Otherwise, **make sure you are on the same page with all other contributer before rebasing**