# Move remote branch tip from one branch to another

Tags: git, commit, rebase

I did a `rebase --onto` to move a previous commit (c4) from master to a feature branch. But I had already pushed master to the remote origin.

So currently now I have

```
c1 - c2 - c3 - c5(master HEAD)
           \
            c4(feature HEAD) - c5(origin/master HEAD)
```

I realize that fixing this will screw up anyone who has pulled in changes from origin/master. But there is only one other developer so this is not that much of an issue. How do I change origin/master so it's not after the feature branch. I'd like it to be this:

```
c1 - c2 - c3 - c5(master HEAD)(origin/master HEAD)
           \
            c4(feature HEAD)
```

Comment: Does your configuration allow you to delete `origin/master`? It could be that simple.

Comment: I have full access to the remote and it's my repo. So I can do whatever is necessary. But if there's a solution that doesn't require deleting `origin/master` that would probably be the best answer to the question.

Comment: So if I was going to delete `origin/master`, I would just delete that remote, add it as the tracking branch for `master`, and then do a `git -f push`. Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe just `git push origin :master`, and then `git push`. Shouldn't need to force it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a forced push from master to origin/master:

```
git push origin master:master --force
```

The other developer will need to `reset` his master to the remote master afterwards (preferably a hard reset after saving his work):

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: I don't understand the `master:master` syntax. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @SeanLynch It means: push master (the first) into master (the second) at the remote origin.

Comment: When I do that I get `denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)`. I don't want to do this because then `c4` will get merged back into master.

Comment: @SeanLynch Did you add the `--force` switch? Maybe the server does not allow forced pushes?

Comment: @TmWolla Yes I added the `--force` switch. I'm not sure why it wouldn't allow forced pushes.

Comment: @SeanLynch That's a setting on the server: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1754553/782822. You should check there.