# Disable `git push --force` locally

Tags: git, bash

I would like to disable git's `--force` flag usage on local machine completely (globally for all the repos I have). I assume it's possible with some bash hook, but where can I read more info about creating one?
Ideally the behavior would be like this: every time I try to use `--force` flag in any push command in any repository - my terminal will show the command abortion and tell me that it's forbidden.

**UPDATE**: Unfortunately none of answers are correct because I **don't** need a repository-located hook. I need a hook on my **local** computer to prevent **me** from using --force flag when pushing to remote.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754491/is-there-a-way-to-configure-git-repository-to-reject-git-push-force)?

Comment: You may find [this](https://gist.github.com/pixelhandler/5718585) useful

Answer (score 4):

The `receive.denyNonFastForwards` config option can do what you want.

> ```
> receive.denyNonFastForwards
> ```
>
> If set to true, `git-receive-pack` will deny a ref update which is
>              not a fast-forward. Use this to prevent such an update via a push,
>              even if that push is forced. This configuration variable is set
>              when initializing a shared repository.

Set this in your personal git configuration with

```
git config --global receive.denyNonFastForwards true
```

Comment: Would this block --force-with-lease as well? I'm trying to condition myself to always force with lease but... habits...

Comment: @Pluc this is exactly the reason I'm here, did you find a solution?